# Method pot-php, mysqli and fpdf

Tags: php, html

I have tried to make a report using **FPDF**.

While sending the form data to the **Query** in **FPDF**, does not show me the data

**Form**

```
include_once('PDF.php');
require 'conexion.php';

$where = "";

if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    $desde = date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['desde']));
    //$hasta = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['hasta']));
    $valor = $_POST['campo'];
    if (empty($_POST['dese'])) {
        $where = "WHERE proveedores LIKE '%".$valor."%' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
    } elseif (empty($POST['campo'])) {
        $where = "WHERE f_elaboracion = '".$desde."' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
    }else{
        $where = "WHERE proveedores LIKE '".$valor."' AND f_elaboracion = '".$desde."' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM retensiones $where";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);?>
<html lang="es">
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h2 style="text-align:center">FORMULARIO</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <form  method="POST" >
                <select name="campo">
                    <option value="2">Proveedor</option>
                    <?php
        $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT proveedores FROM proveedores ORDER BY proveedores ASC");  
            while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                echo '<option value="'.$valores[proveedores].'">'.$valores[proveedores].'</option>';
            }?>
                </select>
                <td>Desde :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input type="date" id="desde" name="desde"/></td>
                <button name="buscar" type="submit"   class="btn btn-info" >Buscar</button>
                <td width="200"><a target="_blank" href="indexpdf.php" class="btn btn-danger">Exportar Busqueda a PDF</a></td>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="row table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>CXL</th>
                        <th>FECHA</th>
                        <th>Concepto</th>
                        <th>Periodo</th>
                        <th>Importe</th>
                        <th>I.V.A.</th>
                        <th>I.S.R.</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
                    {?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['cxl']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['f_elaboracion'])); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['concepto']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['periodo']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo number_format (($row['importe']),'2','.',','); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo number_format (($row['iva']),'2','.',','); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo number_format (($row['isr']),'2','.',','); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php 
                    }?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>      
</body>
</html>
```

**FPDF TEMPLATE**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'pasword.123', 'tesoreria');
if($mysqli->connect_error){
    die('Error en la conexion' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$where = "";

if(isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
    $desde = date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['desde']));
    //$hasta = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['hasta']));
    $valor = $_POST['campo'];

    if (empty($_POST['dese'])) {
        $where = "WHERE proveedores LIKE '%".$valor."%' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
    } else if (empty($POST['campo'])){
        $where = "WHERE f_elaboracion = '".$desde."' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
    } else {
        $where = "WHERE proveedores LIKE '".$valor."' AND f_elaboracion = '".$desde."' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM retensiones $where";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
include_once('PDF.php');    
$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();//Genera el numero de paginas finales
$pdf->AddPage();//Agrega una nueva pagina 

$rows=0;  // inicia el contador de fila
$totalimporte=0;
$totaliva=0;
$totalisr=0;
$pdf->SetXY(10,80);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
$pdf->SetTextColor(3,3,3);//Coor del Texto Negro
while ($fila = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
  $pdf->Cell(20,7, utf8_decode($fila['cxl']),0,0,'L');
  $pdf->Cell(25,7, date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fila['f_elaboracion'])),0,0,'L');     //date strtotime , da el formato dia mes año
$pdf->Cell(45,7, utf8_decode($fila['concepto']),0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(25,7, utf8_decode($fila['periodo']),0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(25,7, number_format (($fila['importe']),'2','.',',') ,0,0,'L');  // numer format , le da el formato en centenas miles y millones
$pdf->Cell(25,7, number_format (($fila['iva']),'2','.',','),0,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(25,7, number_format (($fila['isr']),'2','.',','),0,0,'L');
$pdf->Ln();
$rows++; //suma 1 al contador 
$totalimporte= $totalimporte + ($fila['importe']);
$totaliva = $totaliva + ($fila['iva']);
$totalisr = $totalisr + ($fila['isr']);

if($rows==22) {  // si el numero de fila es igual a 20 
$rows = 0;      //vuelve el contador cero y
$pdf->AddPage();  // agrega una nueva pagina
  }
}   
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
 $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(20,7 ,"TOTALES",1,0,'L');
$pdf->SetX(115);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->Cell(30,10, number_format (($totalimporte),'2','.',',') ,1,0,'L');    
$pdf->Cell(30,10, number_format (($totaliva),'2','.',',') ,1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(30,10, number_format (($totalisr),'2','.',',') ,1,0,'L');

$pdf->Output();//Salida del navegador

mysql_close($conexion);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<a target="_blank" href="indexpdf.php" class="btn btn-danger">Exportar Busqueda a PDF</a>` does not send the form data. You can use Jquery to send the data you want to the PDF template.

```
include_once('PDF.php');
require 'conexion.php';

$where = "";

if (isset($_POST['buscar'])) {
$desde = date('Y-m-d',strtotime ($_POST['desde']));
//$hasta = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['hasta']));
$valor = $_POST['campo'];
if (empty($_POST['dese'])) {
$where = "WHERE proveedores LIKE '%".$valor."%' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
} elseif (empty($POST['campo'])) {
$where = "WHERE f_elaboracion = '".$desde."' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
}else{
$where = "WHERE proveedores LIKE '".$valor."' AND f_elaboracion = '".$desde."' ORDER BY cxl ASC";
}
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM retensiones $where";
$resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);?>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<Script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<Script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#indexPDF").click(function(){
submit('indexpdf.php', 'POST', [
{ name: 'desde', value: $('#desde').val() },
{ name: 'campo', value: $('#campo').val() }
], '_blank');
});
});

function submit(action, method, values, target) {
var form = $('<form/>', {
action: action,
method: method,
target: target
});
$.each(values, function() {
form.append($('<input/>', {
type: 'hidden',
name: this.name,
value: this.value
}));    
});
form.appendTo('body').submit();
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<h2 style="text-align:center">FORMULARIO</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
<form  method="POST" >
<select name="campo">
<option value="2">Proveedor</option>
<?php
$query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT proveedores FROM proveedores ORDER BY proveedores ASC");  
while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
echo '<option value="'.$valores[proveedores].'">'.$valores[proveedores].'</option>';
}?>
</select>
<td>Desde :&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="date" id="desde" name="desde"/></td>
<button name="buscar" type="submit"   class="btn btn-info" >Buscar</button>
<td width="200"><div id="indexPDF" class="btn btn-danger">Exportar Busqueda a PDF</div></td>
</form>
</div>
<div class="row table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>CXL</th>
<th>FECHA</th>
<th>Concepto</th>
<th>Periodo</th>
<th>Importe</th>
<th>I.V.A.</th>
<th>I.S.R.</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php while($row = $resultado->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['cxl']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo date('d/m/Y',strtotime($row['f_elaboracion'])); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['concepto']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['periodo']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format (($row['importe']),'2','.',','); ?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format (($row['iva']),'2','.',','); ?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format (($row['isr']),'2','.',','); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>      
</body>
</html>
```

I changed your code

```
<a target="_blank" href="indexpdf.php" class="btn btn-danger">Exportar Busqueda a PDF</a>
```

to

```
<div id="indexPDF" class="btn btn-danger">Exportar Busqueda a PDF</div>
```

Missing is the Style sheet. I edited the above code to include the style sheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try

Comment: I do not know if they are for the scripts, but I do not see the button "Export Search to PDF", and I do not respect the bootstrap design I do not know if I'm not running well, but at least that button appeals to me as pure text, I do not know what that is? I also tried to run without bootstrap but it works the same way, I run it as you indicated without bootstrap and only the scrpts that you put but I do not know why that button does not appear

Comment: The missing section is the CSS reference. Please look at the code again, I have added <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"> to the code above.

Comment: I also put the extension but the "Export to PDF" button does not do any action, I press it but it does nothing, which you think it should?

Comment: Did you copy my posted code exactly or did you change it?

Comment: Change the following 

target: _blank

to 

'_blank'

Comment: I already activated the button, and it does not generate errors, but I pass the same as with the post, when opening indexpdf.php is generated empty without the search performed

Comment: Change the line <select name="campo"> to <select id="campo" name="campo">

Comment: I still have the same problem, I generate an empty report, I think it may be the initial condition of "indexpdf.php" since it assigns the same condition with respect to the search button, or not?

Comment: In this case, how can I put a condition on the send button to the PDF?

Comment: Getting the criteria to indexphp is completed by my post. If you are still having issues you need to look at the indexphp.php file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used your help a lot, I just need to configure the indexpdf file well,

Comment: Again, I would like to thank you very much for your help, I was wrong in indexpdf, since the library "include_once ('PDF.php');   again, Thank you